# Copying user folder from a crashed Windows 11 laptop

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd, windows-11, user-accounts

I had a Windows 11 laptop that crashed. I had some very important files in my user-folder. So I left the laptop to an Italian computer shop and they removed the internal SSD hard drive and copied the contents to an external hard drive. But the user-folder wasn't copied.

I've done some reading and I read that in Windows 10 the user folder is hidden. I have no idea what it is like in Windows 11? Now I ordered a PCIe to USB adapter and will have a go at it myself. Will it be enough with 'show hidden files' on the old C-drive? Or how will I be able to copy this files in my old user-folder? My new laptop that I will try and read the file from has Windows 10 home edition installed and the crashed laptop was Windows 11 home edition. Will that be an issue? Do I need to update to Window 11 in order to copy my old user-folder?

Comment: Normally you can copy documents / folders from the SSD to another folder on the working PC and take ownership of the files.

Comment: Files or folders being hidden only keeps them "out of sight". It does not in any way prevent access to the files. Any competent PC tech will find it trivial access even hidden files, AND retrieving the user folders is a basic part of any file recovery/backup service.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask for your money back from that Italian computer shop, because
they did an incompetent job of backing up your disk. The only excuse for
their doing a partial backup is if the disk was very seriously damaged
by the crash (which they should have signaled).

To answer the question:

You should have no problem with getting back your user folder,
if the disk wasn't too damaged.

First, to see everything in Explorer, go to the View pane, Options,
View tab. Ensure that:

- "Show hidden f‌iles, folders and drives" is checked
- "Hide extensions for known f‌ile types" is unchecked
- "Hide protected operating system f‌iles (Recommended)" is uncheck

and finish by clicking OK.

If you get a permissions error when copying the user folder, this is
because the folder is owned by a user that is not yourself and that
existed only on the crashed computer. You will need in this case to
[Take Ownership of the folder](https://www.makeuseof.com/windows-10-11-own-folder/).